# Batch duplicate and rename a single file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

```
@echo off
set arg1=%%1
set arg2=%%2
shift
shift
for /L %%i IN (1,1,9) do copy "%arg1%" "%arg2%00%%i.xlsm"
for /L %%i IN (10,1,25) do copy "%arg1%" "%arg2%0%%i.xlsm"
```

I'm having issues trying to get this batch command to run.  I'm new to batch files, but my end goal is this:

```
duplicate "foo.txt" "\Bar\banana"
```

To which I'd find 25 copies in "\Bar", named as such:

```
banana001.xlsm
banana002.xlsm
```

Anyone have ideas?

Answer (score 3):

```
set arg1=%%1
set arg2=%%2
```

should be

```
set arg1=%~1
set arg2=%~2
```

or preferably

```
set "arg1=%~1"
set "arg2=%~2"
```

`%` escapes `%` so `%%2` will place "%2" (literally) into `arg2`

`%n` refers to the contents of argument *n* where n=0 to 9

the `%` needs to be doubled only when referring to a `metavariable` like `i`

The `~` removes the argument's enclosing quotes, if they exist.

The quoted format ensures stray trailing spaces on the `set` line are not included in the value set into the variable.